# Нужно ли выбрасывать исключение в doOnError?

Tags: исключения, rxjava

Как я понимаю, `observable.doOnError()` ловит исключение, а затем пробрасывает его в `subscriber..doOnError()` Но дальше исключение никуда не попадает. Например, следующий код

```
try {
        observable
             ...
             .doOnError(ex -> {
                 Log.e("ERROR", "observable ERROR!", ex);
             })
             ...
             .subscribe(response -> {...},
                        throwable -> {
                             Log.e("ERROR", "subscriber ERROR!", throwable);
                        });
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("ERROR", "catch! ", ex);
}
```

выводит

> observable ERROR! ...
>
> subscriber ERROR! ...

и всё, "catch! ..." не выводится. Нужно ли явно пробрасывать исключение в `doOnError`, например:

```
       .doOnError(ex -> {
                     Log.e("ERROR", "observable ERROR!", ex);
                     throw new Exception(ex); 
                 })
```

и где это лучше делать - в `observable.doOnError()` или `subscriber.doOnError()`? Или я что-то неправильно понимаю?

**UPD**

Но если я выбрасываю исключение (`throw new Exception(ex);`) в `observable.doOnError()`, в `subscriber.doOnError()` выводится сообщение

> io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred.

И если я выбрасываю исключение в `subscriber.doOnError()`, оно всё равно не попадает в блок `catch`. Как сделать так, чтобы оно всё-таки попало в `catch`?

Comment: Почему вы так уверены что к моменту возникновения исключения поток все еще находится в вашем блоке catch?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не подумала об этом... Получается, try-catch тут вообще бессмыслен, его лучше убрать, а обрабатывать исключения на уровне приложения, например, с помощью crashlytics?

Comment: Ваш `doOnError` - это и есть замена для catch